# Making sense of a set notation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I'm trying to make sense of this notation I came across in a post here:
Let $\omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\,:\,0<x<y<2x<2\}$.

Putting $0<x<y<2x<2$ into WolframAlpha gives me the solution interval as:
$0<x<1$ and $x<y<2x$.

What I'm trying to understand is how do you resolve $0<x<y<2x<2$ to $0<x<1$ and $x<y<2x$?

I thought I knew about inequalities but honestly I've never seen one like this.
I'm hoping someone can point me to a book or lecture or anything that I can read to educate myself

Thanks.

Comment: If $0<x<y<2x<2$ then a) $0<2x<2\Leftrightarrow 0<x<1$ holds and b) $x<y<2x$ as well. Conversely, if a) and b) hold, putting all the pieces together gives the big inequality. Basically, you show that the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chain of inequalities is implicitly a logical "AND" of the simpler component inequalities.

So "$0<x<y<2x<2$" means "$0<x$ and $x<y$ and $y<2x$ and $2x<2$".

The first and last of these give you "$0<x$ and $x<1$", i.e., "$0<x<1$".

The middle two give you "$x<y$ and $y<2x$", i.e., "$x<y<2x$".

This is to be interpreted as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$; for a given value of $x$, $y$ ranges between $x$ and $2x$.

This might be taken as limits on a double integral: $\int_0^1\int_x^{2x}f(x,y)\;dy\; dx$.

The region described by the inequalities is the interior of a wedge between the lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$ in the first quadrant, cut off by the vertical line $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for responding and the example. I'll see if I can find something on chained inequalities so I can do some examples.

Answer (score 1):

The chain $0<x<y<2x<2$ is simply the conjunction of all of the individual inequalities: $0<x$ **and** $x<y$ **and** $y<2x$ **and** $2x<2$. Thus, it boils down to saying that $0<x<1$ (since $2x<2$), and $x<y<2x$. If you graph the set $\Omega$ in the plane, you get the open triangle bounded below by the line $y=x$, above by the line $y=2x$, and on the right by the line $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaponse, makes sense.

Comment: @kitaismith: You’re welcome.